# R data.table dynamically filter rows based on columns in j

Tags: r, filter, data.table, lapply, map-function

I am working on a requirement where I need to generate MAPE for few predicted variables. For this I am using the MAP function to generate a summary table with MAPE values in **data.table**. So the result output should have 4 rows x 6 columns, 1 row for each city and 1 city column followed by a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 having MAPE values in each cell.

Below is the sample data and code that I use (**Note - considered a1,a2,a3....as  actual and p1,p2,p3...as predicted**)-

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
id <- seq(1001,1100,1)
city <- sample(1:4,100,replace = T)
a1 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a2 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a3 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a4 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a5 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p1 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p2 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p3 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p4 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p5 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)

df1 <- as.data.table(data.frame(id,city,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5))


sum1 <- df1[, Map(function(x,y) mean(as.numeric(abs(get(x)-get(y))/get(x))*100),
                                                                   paste("a",1:5, sep = ""),
                                                                   paste("p",1:5, sep = "")),by=city]
```

Now I want to generate the same summary for rows where `x==y` then `x > y` and `x < y`.....and the easiest way to do this that I could think is to pass it in **i** but how to do that I am not getting.....when I try to pass it as a `function(x,y) get(x)==get(y)` it gives error

> i has not evaluated to logical, integer or double

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:** As you want to have 3 separate data tables each for `==`, `>` & `<`, I have used `lapply` to process these operations one by one using the same code which you had posted in your post.

Operator (e.g. `==`) is passed to `Map` as `z`. Since this is an 'operator' you can't use `get(z)` so to solve this issue I have used `do.call` to apply `fn` function (i.e. `==` operator) on list of variables.

In `Map` function I have first filtered data based on `fn` value (i.e. `z`) as `x1` & `y1`. Then MAPE formula is applied on these subset to get the final result.

```
lapply(c("==", ">", "<"), 
       function(z) df1[, 
                       Map(function(x, y, fn = z){
                         x1 <- get(x)[do.call(fn, list(get(x), get(y)))]
                         y1 <- get(y)[do.call(fn, list(get(x), get(y)))]
                         mean(as.numeric(abs(x1 - y1) / x1) * 100)
                         },
                         paste0("a", 1:5),
                         paste0("p", 1:5),
                         z), 
                       by = city])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is quite close but would not update filtering dynamically. What I was looking for is something like,using the sign column create summary output similar to one that gets generated from my code. So for example filter the rows for sign == "eq" and get one summary table. then filter the rows with sign == "lt" and generate the summary table. This filtering of rows I wanted the code to do dynamically. Currently we will have to create this column sign & then use DT as input to another data.table and do the filtering. Filtering should be done dynamically.

Comment: I am not sure if I am fully with you on this part but see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Allow me to explain again. Basically MAPE needs to be calculated, similar to what I have in my code (or some other better way). Now these MAPE needs to be calculated for each predicted variable for rows that are `=`,`<`,`>` separately, so the filtering of rows need to happen dynamically and MAPE needs to get calculated. So in the end I would have 3 sets of MAPE values to look at and compare. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This latest update seems to be doing the trick. Need your help in understanding how it is working. Basically function(z) in that you are calling data.table and using the Map function and within that you are passing fn = z which is then passed using do.call..... I was keen to understand how it is getting executed and the flow. Please help by share some explanation. I am sure it would help all users who would look at this interesting code you have written.